# Reset togglebutton on viewpager swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, togglebutton

Situation:  I'm making an app that has 3 fragments that the user can swipe between using a viewpager. On each fragment they have a toggle button that shows/hides a answer.

Issue: When you click the toggle button on the first fragment it turns on. Then when you swipe to the second fragment and swipe back to the first one, the toggle button is still check ON (it's still showing the answer). How can i make it so when you swipe forward then the back, that it will reset the buttons state.

I thought it was gonna be something simple like putting this in the fragment

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    showHideButton.setChecked(false);
}
```

This didnt work. I have also looked at a bunch of other posts similer to this but nothing was working. I apologize i wont be able to check back here to answer questions until tonight because i am at work and i was just taking a short break to ask this question.

EDIT:

Activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.Menu;
public class Activity10_1 extends FragmentActivity {

Fragment10_1 frag = new Fragment10_1();

ViewPager pager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Set up pager and fragment manager.
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    MyFragmentPageAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPageAdapter(fm);
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    pageChange();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity10_1, menu);
    return true;
}
public void pageChange(){
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {}
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                    switch(position){
                    case 0:
                        frag.getShowHideButton().setChecked(false);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        frag.getShowHideButton().setChecked(false);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        frag.getShowHideButton().setChecked(false);
                        break;
                    default:
                        frag.getShowHideButton().setChecked(false);
                    }
                }

          });

}

}
```

Pager Adapter:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MyFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

DataHolder10_1 dh = new DataHolder10_1();

final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

public MyFragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

// method will be involked when a page is requested to create
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0){
    //Create bundle.
    Bundle data = new Bundle();

    //Instantiate fragment.
    Fragment10_1 myFragment = new Fragment10_1();



    //Add data to bundle.
    data.putInt("pageNumberData", arg0 + 1);
    data.putString("questionData", dh.getQuestions()[arg0]);
    data.putString("answerData", dh.getAnswers()[arg0]);

    //Send bundle to fragment.
    myFragment.setArguments(data);

    return myFragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

}
```

Fragment:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class Fragment10_1 extends Fragment {

private int pageNumber;
private String question;
private String answer;

//declare TextViews.
private TextView pageNumberTextView;
private TextView questionTextView;
private TextView answerTextView;

private String origMessage;// saves message of answer for switching between show and hide.

//colors for switching between show and hide.
private int showColor;
private int hideColor;

//declare toggle button.
private ToggleButton showHideButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Get bundle data.
    Bundle data = getArguments();

    // Get integer data of the key current page from the bundle
    pageNumber = data.getInt("pageNumberData", 0);
    question = data.getString("questionData");
    answer = data.getString("answerData");



}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState){


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment10_1, container, false);

    pageNumberTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pageCount1);
    questionTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.question1);
    answerTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    showHideButton = (ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);



    showHideButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean on){

            if(on){
                //change color and text if button is set to show answer.
                answerTextView.setTextColor(showColor);
                answerTextView.setText(answer);
            }else{
                //default answer to hidden properties.
                answerTextView.setTextColor(hideColor);
                answerTextView.setText(origMessage);
            }
        }
    });

    //grab colors from text views for switching between show and hide.
    showColor = questionTextView.getTextColors().getDefaultColor();
    hideColor = answerTextView.getTextColors().getDefaultColor();

    //set original message.
    origMessage = getString(R.string.answer);



    //create Text views and button down here.
    pageNumberTextView.setText("Page: " + pageNumber + "/3");
    questionTextView.setText(question);

    return view;
}
public ToggleButton getShowHideButton(){

    return showHideButton;
}
}
```

Right now im trying to use the OnPageChangeListener. The app comes up fine but it is causing it to crash when i swipe.

Edit 2: arn't the widget being created here

```
private TextView pageNumberTextView;
private TextView questionTextView;
private TextView answerTextView;
private ToggleButton showHideButton;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState){


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment10_1, container, false);

    pageNumberTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pageCount1);
    questionTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.question1);
    answerTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    showHideButton = (ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
```

Comment: Are you making any progress?

Comment: Sadly no i haven't :/ I looked up an example but they implemented that on the activity. My button is on the fragments so i'm not sure how i'm going to reset it from the activity. Now, to be honest i haven't had much time to really look into it. Any help is appreciated, i'll let you know if i figure it out.

Comment: So, are you saying that onPageChangeListener won't work for you?

Comment: Im saying im not really sure how to make it work. I have put up my code in the post. I'm trying your suggestion with the pageChange() method under activity. I'm using a get method to get the button from the fragment class. It is cause my app to crash when i swipe to the second page. Any ideas?

Comment: It's a lot of code to look through.  But one thing I see is you're setting setOnPageChangeListener() in pageChange().  That's too late - you need to do it in onCreate() so that the listener is ready when the user swipes.

Comment: But im calling the pageChange() method inside the onCreate. Is that not ok? I kinda figured it would do the same thing.

Comment: Oh, my mistake.  I was thinking of onPageSelected.  Anyway, apparently it is calling your listener.  Where is it faulting?  Also, where do you add "frag" to the FragmentPageAdapter?  (disclaimer: I'm familiar with PagerAdapter but not with FragmentPagerAdapter, but still there must be a way to add fragments.)

Comment: The only reason i have "frag" on my activity was to try to get the toggle button. otherwise i wouldnt have it in the activity at all. the pagerAdapter makes fragments using the getItem() method. that gets run 3 times based on the getCount() method (at least im pretty sure thats how it works).

Comment: Also it seems to be faulting at the onPageSelected. The error messages are giving me a NullPointerException. I just tested for what position gives me and it said 1. So im guessing the problem is getting the toggle button from the fragment. I am not really sure how to do it.

Comment: Ok, yes you are right: getItem() will create the fragments.  So, then "frag" is never really used.  In fact, I think the problem is that frag.onCreate() never gets called (since "frag" is never displayed) and thus its layout is never inflated and the widgets (particularly R.id.toggleButton1) never get created.  Instead, what you need to do in onPageSelected is retrieve the actual fragment and fetch R.id.toggleButton1 from that.

Comment: The only reason this line "Fragment10_1 frag = new Fragment10_1();" is in the activity is so i can try to recieve the toggle button from the fragment. The app comes up fine and i can tell that the fragments are being created and displayed just fine. the problem is when i try to get the toggle button using  frag.getShowHideButton(). If i took out Fragment10_1 frag = new Fragment10_1(); and the pageChange() method, the app would run just fine except that the button wouldn't reset when changeing pages.

Comment: Exactly where is the fault happening?  Are you getting a null pointer reference from frag.getShowHideButton().setChecked(false);?  If so, that's because the widgets in "frag" never get created.

Comment: I put up a second edit. arn't the widgets being created there? That's in the fragment class.  Edit: and yes that is where i am getting the null pointer reference.

Comment: Where is "there".  Keep in mind that you are creating four fragments: one in onCreate called "frag", the other three via getItem().  The widgets get created for each fragment, independently, during the callback to Fragment10_1.onCreate()fragment.BTW, can you expand the tabs - it's hard to read.

Comment: by "there" I was refering to the second edit that i put in bottom of the post. Also im not really sure what you mean by expand the tabs

Comment: Ok,  I see what you added.  Yes, you have good code in onCreate.  What I'm saying is that onCreate is never called for "frag".  Please post your stack trace and I'll verify my statement.  As for expanded tabs, I'm referring to your code: all of it is smashed tight to the left - no indentation is showing up in my browser.

Comment: So are you saying that i need to do something like frag.onCreate inside my activity class? Could you put an edit in your reply showing me what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ViewPage.OnPageChangeListener.  Set the listener and implement onPageSelected().

In onPageSelected(), you need to fetch the currently active page.  There are different ways to do this.  One way is to keep your own array of fragments.  I'll give a brief example:

Add this to MyFragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public Fragment findFragmentByPosition(int position) {
    FragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = getFragmentPagerAdapter();
    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
            "android:switcher:" + getViewPager().getId() + ":"
                    + fragmentPagerAdapter.getItemId(position));
}
```

In onPageSelected (int position), do this (and remove the existing code):

```
Fragment10_1 curFrag = pagerAdapter.findFragmentByPosition (position);
curFrag.getShowHideButton().setChecked(false);
```

Comment: It's giving me a bunch of errors. Its telling me to make methods for getFragmentPagerAdapter, getSupportFragmentManager, getViewPager in the MyFragmentPageAdapter class. Do i need some kinda import statment for those?

Comment: You might.  If you're using Eclipse, it will generate the imports for you.  If you don't like this solution, you can try another one: instead of creating fragments in getItem(), create them in the constructor and simply return them in getItem(). Then you can use getItem() to retrieve your existing fragments in onPageSelected().

Comment: How do i return something from a constructor, constructors dont have a return statment? wouldnt i have to make it something like "public Fragment MyFragmentPageAdapter..." Which would mean that it's not a constructor anymore.

Comment: You don't return them from the constructor; you return them from getItem().

Comment: "create them in the constructor and simply return them in getItem()" This is the part that confuses me. if i make them in the constructor how do i get them to the getItem()? I tried making a parameter to pass the fragment, but then that told me to get ride of the @override. is that ok?

Comment: How about storing them in an array member variable?

Comment: So i just went to talk to my instructor about this and she told me that I shouldn't really waste my time on it. This whole thing was part of a assignment, but resetting the toggle button wasn't really part of it. I just was gonna do that on my own cause that just seemed like something it should do. This is taking me longer then i thought to figure out. Id rather not waste anymore of your time on something small like this. I understand what your getting at though, if i have time somewhere down the road ill come back and figure it out. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Ok, that's fine.  I think you'll be getting back to it, though with some future "real" app.  Good luck.  If you don't mind, please select my answer as "correct".  Thanks.